# What is the keyboard shortcut for ⇒ in your Scala editor of choice?

Tags: scala

The Unicode operator `\u21D2` "`⇒`" (sometimes writtten as `=>`) is a common lexical identifier prevalent in the Scala programming language used in functional combinators, function definitions, case-match statements, etc. I normally have to copy-and-paste this operator into my code from someplace else, but that can get really annoying.

Does anyone know of shortcuts to produce this symbol in your IDE of choice? I typically use programs like JetBrains IntelliJ, SublimeText, and VIM.

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer the Unicode symbol instead of the `=>` that is, I believe, in pretty common usage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA under

Preferences -> Editor -> CodeStyle -> Scala

In the Tab 'Other' are options to automatically insert several unicode characters.

[image]

Comment: Cool, I've seen this replacement in some code samples. BUT WHY THOUGH?

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ, I've created a live template of the form `$PARAMS$ ⇒ $BODY$`. This lets you easily insert the `⇒` character.

Answer (score 0):

For emacs, there's `(global-prettify-symbols-mode)`, which just displays `⇒` over `=>`. It still writes `=>` to the file in the end.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're using the `rfc1345` input method (see `toggle-input-method`), you can just enter `&=>`.